# Prove: if $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \sigma(A_1)$ then $ \sigma(A_1)= \sigma(A_2)$

Tags: measure-theory

Prove: if $A_1,A_2$ are families of subsets of $X$ $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \sigma(A_1)$ then $ \sigma(A_1)= \sigma(A_2)$. Here, $\sigma(A)$ denotes [the sigma algebra which is generated by $A$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generated_%CF%83-algebra_(by_sets)).

$\supseteq:$ $A_2\subset \sigma(A_1)$ then $A_2$ is closed to compliment and infinite union, which is $\sigma(A_2)$ so $\sigma(A_2)\subseteq \sigma(A_1)$

$\subseteq$ let $x_i\in \sigma (A_1)$ therefore $\bigcup_{n}^{\infty} x_i\in \sigma (A_1)$ but for all $i$ $x_i\in A_2$ therefore  $\bigcup_{n}^{\infty} x_i\subseteq \bigcup A_2$ and $\bigcup A_2\subseteq \sigma(A_1)$

If I take $x_i^C\in \sigma(A_1)$ how can I show that $x_i^C\in \sigma(A_2)$?

Comment: What is $\sigma(A)$?

Comment: @user170039 it is a well-known, and from context quite clear, notation for the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$.

Comment: We shouldn't have to guess what $\sigma(A)$ is by looking at the tag. My first thought when looking at the title was the spectrum of an operator and was quite confused as such.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: Probably, it is. But I found it confusing.

Comment: I have edited the post accordingly

Comment: **Hint:** $A_1\subseteq A_2\implies \sigma(A_1)\subseteq \sigma(A_2)$.

Comment: No, "[If] $A_2\subset \sigma(A_1)$ then $A_2$ is closed to compliment and infinite union" is simply not true. (That says any subset of  a $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra, obviously nonsense...)

Comment: @user170039 why is it true?

Comment: For any set $A$, you have $A\subseteq \sigma(A)$. Hence $A_1\subseteq A_2$, combined with $A_2\subseteq \sigma(A_2)$ gives $A_1\subseteq \sigma(A_2)$. Now since $\sigma(A_1)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A_1$ and $\sigma(A_2)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $A_1$, you get $\sigma(A_1)\subseteq \sigma(A_2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have obviously

- $\sigma\left(\sigma(A)\right) = \sigma(A)$ for any family $A$ and
- $A_1\subseteq A_2 \Rightarrow \sigma(A_1 )\subseteq \sigma(A_2)$

Hence,
$$A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \sigma(A_1) \Rightarrow \sigma(A_1 )\subseteq \sigma(A_2) \subseteq \sigma\left(\sigma(A_1)\right) = \sigma(A_1)$$

So, you are done.

Comment: Why do $A_1\subseteq A_2\Rightarrow \sigma(A_1)\subseteq \sigma(A_2)$? $ \sigma(A_2)$ is the smallest sigma algebra that contains $A_2$ and $A_1\subseteq A_2$ then $\sigma(A_1)\subset \sigma(A_2)$?

Answer (score 1):

You proved that if $A_2 \subseteq \sigma(A_1)$ then $\sigma (A_2) \subseteq \sigma (A_1)$.

To get the other one, notice that $A_1 \subseteq A_2$ implies $A_1 \subseteq \sigma(A_2)$. Now apply your previous logic.

Comment: Why does $A_1\subseteq A_2$ implies $A_1\subseteq \sigma(A_2)$?

Comment: Surely you are aware of the fact that $A \subseteq \sigma(A)$.